# Prepared Batch/Bulk Insert w/ Generated Column

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with my helper function that handles prepared bulk inserts. If there is a generated column, the helper breaks because `Column count doesn't match value count at row...`.

The statement I'm using is `$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES ".$values;`

I had assumed this wouldn't be an issue because its a generated and stored column. Is there a way around this issue without having to specify the columns I am inserting on? Possibly ignore this column entirely? The only use I see of `IGNORE` is with rows.

Comment: Showing us the schema or at least a good example of a schema like what you are using would be really really helpful

Comment: That's not a SQL statement, it's a PHP statement which creates a string which (hopefully) contains a SQL statement. Please show us the exact SQL statement that is being created.

Comment: @kmoser technically they never said it was either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must list all columns except the generated one

like you see in the [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

```
CREATE TABLE triangle (
  sidea DOUBLE,
  sideb DOUBLE,
  sidec DOUBLE AS (SQRT(sidea * sidea + sideb * sideb))
);
INSERT INTO triangle (sidea, sideb) VALUES(1,1),(3,4),(6,8);
```

As you can see sidec will be generated and so is not put into the INSERT clause